# Java Disposable pattern

Tags: java, garbage-collection, dispose

C# supports disposable pattern for deterministic garbage collection using the [dispose pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx).

Is there such pattern for java?

Java 7 has [`autoclosable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), which you can use with try finally blocks to invoke the `close` method.

What about versions prior to 7?

Is there a disposable pattern (deterministic garbage collection) for Java 5 or 6?

Comment: I'm afraid, no, you must do it manually.

Comment: The AutoCloseable has no impact on Garbage collection. What it does is ensure resources are clean up correctly. Are you sure the C# pattern has any effect on the GC?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that neither C#'s `using` nor Java 7's `try`-with-resources pattern offer deterministic *garbage collection*. They offer deterministic *resource control*. I know I'm being pedantic about it, but it's an important difference.

Comment: @PeterLawrey looks like we cross-posted the same thing. C# is just like Java's; there's no real effect on the GC by default, although some patterns (particularly Microsoft's own suggested pattern) recommend suppressing finalization -- the first step in garbage collection. Regardless, the object memory is not reclaimed immediately.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The closest prior to Java 7 is just "manual" try/finally blocks:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(...);
try {
  // Use input
} finally {
  input.close();
}
```

The `using` statement was one of the things I found nicest about C# when I first started using C# 1.0 from a Java background. It's good to see it finally in Java 7 :)

You should also consider [`Closeables`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Closeables.html) in Guava - it allows you to not worry about whether or not a reference is null (just like a `using` statement does) and optionally "logs and swallows" exceptions thrown when closing, to avoid any such exception from effectively "overwriting" an exception thrown from the try block.

Comment: Doesn't that potentially leak a resource? Wouldn't it be better to initialize `input` to `null` outside the `try` and to construct the `FileInputStream` inside the `try`. Then in the `finally` check for a non-`null` instance and close it. (I am pretty sure it needs to be initialized to `null` outside the `try` because otherwise assignment cannot be guaranteed.)

Comment: @NoelWidmer: If an asynchronous exception could occur between the assignment and entering the `try` block, then the same exception could presumably occur after the constructor completes but before the resulting reference is assigned to the `input` variable. But in Java at least, I don't believe that's an issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right. (Although I don't know if async could be an issue in Java)

Comment: @Noel: By asynchronous exceptions, I mean exceptions that can be thrown at entirely arbitrary points.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know what you meant. Those nasty beasts are the reason I commented initially.

Answer (score 6):

The entire purpose of the disposal pattern is to support C#'s unique `using (temporaryObject)`  pattern. Java has had nothing like that pattern before 7.

All Java objects that had resources supported the disposal pattern via manually closing the object that held resources.

Comment: I know its an old post, but for completeness its fair to say its the other way around. The whole purpose of `using` is to assure that disposable objects in local context are indeed disposed without requiring try/finally enclosure. Disposable pattern itself is used frequently outside of local context, and thus without `using`, especially if object disposed contains references to other disposable objects.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is try with resources.

```
try ( FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(...);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(...) ) {
  // Use input
}
```

The resource has to be Closeable (or AutoCloseable), of course.

Comment: It is clear from the OPs question that he already knows about this, and that he is asking for how this could be done before Java 7...